# how to align icon inside edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-edittext

i want to align icon and text hint inside Edittext. but the icon overlap the left boundry.i want to align it at some distance from left side and the text hint start after a small gap.Here is my code but it is not working properly. For Example like google search option. Please suggest me how to do it. Thanks in advance.

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="Mobile Number"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/mobile_icon">
    </EditText>
```

Comment: can you make a screen shot with how it looks now?

Comment: due to low reputation i can't post the screen shot :(

Comment: it is like google search box.

Comment: http://postimage.org and post the link

Comment: https://plus.google.com/photos/115585035204792909450/albums/5599113500585388033/5962172769461530962?banner=pwa&authkey=CP3uq8zM2JH9LA&pid=5962172769461530962&oid=115585035204792909450

Comment: Give 2-3 blank spaces @ android:hint="   Mobile Number"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use that code

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
               android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="Mobile Number"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/mobile_icon">
    </EditText>
```

Answer (score 4):

set `android:drawablePadding="5dp"` for EditText.